# Como fazer um elemento ficar em cima do outro com o :after?

Tags: css, css3

Utilizando o pseudoelemento `:after`, criei uma legenda para imagem. Como posso fazer para que a legenda fique em cima da imagem e não embaixo?

```css
.estrutura{
  width:10%;
  height:30%;
  }

.estrutura:after{
  position: fixed; 
  content:"Estrutura";
  width:20%;
  height:20px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="estrutura">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a2/Biandintz_eta_zaldiak_-_modified2.jpg/550px-Biandintz_eta_zaldiak_-_modified2.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: O encima que você quer dizer, seria antes ou sobre? se for antes você pode usar o `:before` assim o **content** é posto antes da imagem

Comment: Em cima da imagem. No rodapé dela. Na parte debaixo.

Comment: já tentou usar o `z-index`?

Comment: Execute o Snippet e abra em tela cheia para poder ver o elemento criado

Answer (score 1):

Isso deve resolver seu problema. O `position` do `.estrutura:after` esta como `relative`, e foi acrescentado o `top: -32px` para fazer o texto subir e ficar em cima da imagem.

```css
.estrutura{
  width:10%;
  height:30%;
  }

.estrutura:after{
  position: relative; 
  content:"Estrutura";
  width:20%;
  height:20px;
  top: -32px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="estrutura">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a2/Biandintz_eta_zaldiak_-_modified2.jpg/550px-Biandintz_eta_zaldiak_-_modified2.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ao usar `position: fixed;`, o elemento irá se posicionar em relação ao *documento* (janela toda) e não ao *elemento-pai*.

Você deve setar `position: relative;` ao *elemento-pai* para que o pseudo-elemento `:after` seja posicionado dentro dele. Em seguida com os estilos `top` e `left` você posiciona ele onde você desejar sobre o *elemento-pai*:

```css
.estrutura{
  width:10%;
  height:30%;
  position: relative;
  }

.estrutura:after{
  position: absolute; 
  content:"Estrutura";
  width:20%;
  height:20px;
  background-color: blue;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="estrutura">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a2/Biandintz_eta_zaldiak_-_modified2.jpg/550px-Biandintz_eta_zaldiak_-_modified2.jpg">
</div>
```

Note que como você está restringindo as dimensões do *elemento-pai* `.estrutura` menor que a própria imagem, a dimensão do `:after` irá se basear nesse tamanho também.